# Apache Camel load external XSLT contentCache duration

Tags: caching, tomcat, xslt, apache-camel

I am using Apache Camel on a web-app and I want to call external xslt stylesheet.

I am using the absolute file URI (until now I was not able to use the relative file URI on Tomcat)

The Camel doc refer the following option :

> contentCache  default:true    Camel 2.6: Cache for the resource content (the stylesheet file) when it is loaded. If set to false Camel will reloader the stylesheet file on each message processing. This is good for development.

But I haven't find anything about the duration of this cache.

Is there anyway to know the default value of this cache duration and to change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is cached without a timeout and there currently isn't an option to change it (see the [source code here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/xslt/XsltComponent.java)).

Feel free to log a [CAMEL enhancement request in JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL) and we can possibly add support for specifying a custom timeout.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the way i found to reset this cache is to restart tomcat.

Comment: We should probably add JMX support for being able to purge the cache from JMX as well. And get some stats of the cache.